# What does $[m](T)$ mean in the context of algebraic curve divisors?

Tags: notation, elliptic-curves, divisor-sum

In Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (page 95), it says

> Letting $T \in E$ [an elliptic curve] with $[m]T' = T$, there is similarly a function $g$ satisfying $$\text{div}(g) = [m]*(T) - [m]*(\mathcal{O}) = \sum_{R \in \text{the m-torsion}} (T' + R)-(R)$$

I know that $[m]T$ refers to multiplication by $m$ (addition $m$ times), and (.) refers to the point as a divisor, but what does $[m](T)$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverman's notation here is $[m]^*(T)$ **not** $[m]*(T)$ and **not** $[m](T)$.

Here $[m]$ is the "multiplication by $m$" map from $E$ to $E$
and $[m]^*(T)$ is the pullback operator on divisors induced
by $[m]$. For a separable isogeny $\phi$, then by definition
(earlier in the book) $\phi^*(P)$ is the sum of $(Q)$ over the $(Q)$
for which $\phi(Q)=P$. So $[m]^*(T)$ here is the sum of the $(U)$
with $[m](U)=T$. These are the $T'+R$ for one fixed $T'$
with $[m](T')=T$ and $[m](R)=O$,
as stated in the given formula.